# Non-ascii characters being consumed incorrectly by Apache-camel sftp consumer

Tags: java, apache-camel, camel-ftp

I am using a simple camel sftp route such as this:

```
.(sftp:account@host/some-directory?password=somePassword&charset=utf-8&delay=10000&preMove=.processing&move=.done)
```

It polls the sftp server grabbing files and persisting the data to a database. The files on the server are encoded in utf-8, here is a sample name with a special character:

María

This character is consumed by the route and saved as:

Mar??????a

Any idea as to why these characters are being consumed incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, there was an issue with the BeanIODataFormat marshaling the data. The default encoding for the BeanIODataFormat was set to ascii. To solve the issue I had to set the BeanIODataFormat encoding to utf-8 manually.